# Google apps script, get values from row(s) based on a specific cell value

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to display data from the whole row where Username matches 123@gmail.com. My google sheet looks like below.

```
Timestamp           Username        from        to
24/03/2015 22:21:20 123@gmail.com   17/03/2015  24/03/2015
24/03/2015 22:21:20 abc@gmail.com   18/03/2015  26/03/2015
24/03/2015 22:21:20 123@gmail.com   16/03/2015  26/03/2015
24/03/2015 22:21:20 123@gmail.com   03/03/2015  04/04/2015
24/03/2015 22:21:20 abc@gmail.com   04/03/2015  18/03/2015
```

I want to display the data like the below using apps script.

```
Timestamp           Username        from         to
24/03/2015 22:21:20 123@gmail.com   17/03/2015  24/03/2015
24/03/2015 22:21:20 123@gmail.com   16/03/2015  26/03/2015
24/03/2015 22:21:20 123@gmail.com   03/03/2015  04/04/2015
```

To display the result can I use this?

```
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  app.add(app.createHTML('data from table'))
  return app
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to display the information as a web application, or as a container-bound message box kind of thing?

Comment: Or as sidebar that opens up from the right, you can do it that way also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIApp service is deprecated, you would use HTML service for something similar, but, if all you want is to display the info for that email address, you could try this script:

This will open up a simple message box like an alert.  If you tweak this code, notice that the new line character is `\\n` instead of `\n`.

```
function showDataForEmail(){

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    var msg = "";

    for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {

        if(values[i][1] === "123@gmail.com") {

            msg += values[i][0] + " " + values[i][1] + " " + values[i][2] + " " + values[i][3] + "\\n"

        }

    }

    Browser.msgBox(msg);

}
```

Comment: how about,  matching rows I put into an array and return this array as json output ?